# Scaling whole Game. How does fullscreen work?

Tags: java, 2d, scaling

As title say, I've got 2 problems. First is how to scale whole game "correctly".
I made 2D game, written in java without external libraries. "Main" resolution is 1280x720, I made some primitive scaling by scaling every Image or collision box separately, but its not good idea... I cant predict every aspect ratio and resolution of any future players, so i can't calculate scaling for everyone. The question is how do I do that correctly?

Second thing is how does fullScreen work? Is this just a game scaled to max monitor resolution without window's Frame ? Or is it something different

EDIT:
I made up an idea just a second ago, is there any way to treat whole screen - many many BufferedImages, graphics objects as one for example BufferedImage, an d then scale it to resolution that i want using g.drawImagE(image, x, y, width, height, observer)??

Comment: Too broad, sorry.  Scaling in your game works differently than any other application, you'll have to decide how scaling should work.  Fullscreen works as described in the docs, please read them.

Comment: So... Could u tell me how this should works ? Because i dont have any idea except one described above. Or atleast if u can, tell me where  i can find good source of knowledge of that topic. And by fullscreen docs, did u mean that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html ?